# Mysterious externalSubmit failure on an externalQuestion in Mechanical Turk.I

Tags: mechanicalturk

I'm surprised to be even asking this question, but I'm trying to submit a HIT on an external question, and I just get this error:  "There was a problem submitting your results for this HIT."

The funny thing is the form is copied over almost exactly from the php code [here](http://smallsocialsystems.com/blog/?p=95).

```
<form id="mturk_form" method="POST" action="https://www.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit">
    <input type="hidden" id="assignmentId" name="assignmentId" value="2V7395SW6NG1V6K6INAB5F1F1YHUG7">
    <input id="submitButton" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Complete HIT">
</form>
```

Am I missing something really obvious?

Even a pointer to the documentation would be nice, I can't find official documentation for externalSubmit anywhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out the documentation on [exernalForms](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_ExternalQuestionArticle.html)

Without seeing the exact code you are using, it could be a few things...

1 - If you are testing things out and have the assignmentId hard coded into the form, it may have already been submitted, or you may be crossing between the sandbox and the production environment. I've managed to do both. :)

2 - If you have any other input elements with really long names or nested arrays (see [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=84581&tstart=0)) mTurk may not handle it too well.

3 - Allegedly, some browsers don't like it when you name the submit button "submit", as noted [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=22821&tstart=25). I usually name my submit buttons "commit", and have not had this problem.

4 - You may have to also submit the hitId as a hidden field (the same way you submit the assignmentId). Although it is not mentioned in the official docs, it has [mentioned in the forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=228954&#228954).

Comment: I was just using a hard-coded hitId so it was obvious how it looked post-templating, BUT I was trying to submit a HIT on behalf of a different user. So I think the problem was that I didn't have the right cookie. Thanks for your answer though! Forum reference about cookies: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=214095

Comment: I was having this problem, and the exact cause was number 4. Adding the assignmentId was not enough, I needed the workerId as well! This is mentioned in the link you posted.

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, the problem here was that I was testing by trying to submit the form on behalf of a different worker. Amazon tracks workers via cookies to make sure that submissions come from the worker who accepted the HIT.

Comment: It's a good idea to use the "sandbox" for testing. It has all the functionality of the real MTurk site, but it doesn't matter if you make any mistakes. https://requestersandbox.mturk.com/developer/sandbox

Comment: I did use sandbox, and didn't make this mistake there. It was in testing the real version that I ran into the problem.